# Mysql : Error in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is the trigger im trying to add. But here is the error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'create trigger tgr_insert before insert on `nuss_order`  for
>   each row ' at line 2 .

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists tgr_insert
create trigger tgr_insert before insert on `nuss_order`  
for each row 
begin  
  declare a int;declare b varchar(14);declare d varchar(8);  
  set a = (select `id` from `nuss_order` where `id` = new.id);  
  set d = (select `date` from `nuss_order` where `date` = new.date);  
if (a>=100) then  
  if(a>=1000) then  
    set b = 'BX' + d + cast(a as varchar);  
  else  
    b = 'BX' + d + concat('0',cast(a as varchar));  
  end if;  
else  
  if(a>=10) then  
    b = 'BX' + d + concat('00',cast(a as varchar));  
  else  
   b = 'BX' + d + concat('000',cast(a as varchar));  
  end if;  
end if;  
set new.oid = b;  
end
```

I can't find the error, if someone could help me it would be very nice. Thanks

Comment: Put the drop trigger line before changing  the delimiter,end it with `end$$` and change back the delimiter

Comment: Thank u very much!It works!